# asp.net page lifecycle

Tags: asp.net

How to get post back data in page pre-init stage? Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the

```
Request[key]
```

dictionary directly

EDIT: But, as Oded said, no ASP.NET "services". You get the raw post back data and have to do everything self.

EDIT2:

```
var val = Request["NAME_OF_MY_HTML_INPUT_ELEMENT"];
```

not testes, but should also work:

```
var val = Request[myHiddenFieldControl.UniqueID];
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

Post back data is not available at that point as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

> If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet been restored from view state.

Comment: I know, but I want to get this.

Comment: @zanhtet - And I want to win the lottery. I guess we both won't get what we want.